# Loop through directory with space in the name

Tags: bash, shell-script, directory

I am trying to write a script that will loop through directories, and rename the file in the sub directory to match that of the directory name.  I am running into an issue where if a directory has spaces in the name, then that name is split up and I can't do anything with it like I need to.

For example, the folder structure is:

```
TopLevel
->this is a test
-->test.txt
```

My script so far is:

```
#!/bin/sh
topLevel="/dir1/dir2/TopLevel"
for dir in $(ls $topLevel)
do
    echo $dir # for testing purposes to make sure i'm getting the right thing
    # Get name of directory - i know how to do this
    # Rename file to match the name of the directory, with the existing extension - i know how to do this
done
```

My expected output would be

`/dir1/dir2/TopLevel/this is a test`

However, the actual output is

```
this
is
a
test
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?  It's been awhile since I've done shell scripting. I'm trying to take this script one piece at a time and I seem to be stuck on getting this iteration down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the main reasons why you should [never try to parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you just use shell globs, you can do:

```
for dir in /dir1/dir2/TopLevel/*/
do
    echo "$dir" ## note the quotes, those are essential
done
```

#### Comments

- Note how I use `for dir in /dir1/dir2/TopLevel/*/` and not just `for dir in /dir1/dir2/TopLevel/*`. This is to only iterate over directories. If you want both directories and files, use `for f in /dir1/dir2/TopLevel/*`.
- The quotes around `$dir` are essential, you should always quote variables, especially if they contain whitespace.

Further reading:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)?
- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)?
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)? (advanced)

Comment: Great, thank you for the assistance!